urllib3.exceptions.ReadTimeoutError: HTTPSConnectionPool(host='my-opensearch-domain.com', port=443): Read timed out. (read timeout=15)
I’m running a Python script that bulk-indexes documents into an OpenSearch domain. Sometimes the bulk requests fail with ReadTimeoutError exceptions, similar to what you see below:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/.../urllib3/connectionpool.py", line 536, in _make_request
    response = conn.getresponse()
  ...
urllib3.exceptions.ReadTimeoutError: HTTPSConnectionPool(host='my-opensearch-domain.com', port=443): Read timed out. (read timeout=15)

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

requests.exceptions.ReadTimeout: HTTPSConnectionPool(host='my-opensearch-domain.com', port=443): Read timed out. (read timeout=15)

I see these timeouts intermittently during _bulk indexing operations. Some batches succeed, while others time out after the default read_timeout.
What I’ve tried:
•   Ensuring my internet connection is stable.
•   Running smaller batch sizes (e.g., 100 docs at a time).
•   Confirmed the OpenSearch cluster is healthy and has enough resources.
•   Verified that indexing works most of the time, except under heavier load.
Questions:
•   How can I prevent these intermittent ReadTimeoutError exceptions?
•   Are there configuration options (timeouts, retries) I can tweak in the OpenSearch Python client or requests library?
•   Are there best practices for large bulk indexing jobs in OpenSearch?
Any guidance on resolving these timeouts or best practices for handling large bulk indexing jobs would be appreciated.
import json
import logging
import time
import boto3
from requests_aws4auth import AWS4Auth
from opensearchpy import OpenSearch, RequestsHttpConnection

# Configure basic logging (ERROR only to reduce verbosity)
logger = logging.getLogger(__name__)
logger.setLevel(logging.ERROR)

# Configuration (use placeholders, no PII)
AWS_REGION = "us-east-1"  # Replace as needed
OPENSEARCH_ENDPOINT = "your-opensearch-domain.us-east-1.es.amazonaws.com"  # Replace with your endpoint
INDEX_NAME = "test-index"

def create_opensearch_client(timeout=15, max_retries=3, pool_maxsize=10):
    session = boto3.Session(region_name=AWS_REGION)
    credentials = session.get_credentials()
    awsauth = AWS4Auth(
        credentials.access_key,
        credentials.secret_key,
        AWS_REGION,
        "es",
        session_token=credentials.token,
    )

    return OpenSearch(
        hosts=[{"host": OPENSEARCH_ENDPOINT, "port": 443}],
        http_auth=awsauth,
        use_ssl=True,
        verify_certs=True,
        timeout=timeout,
        max_retries=max_retries,
        retry_on_timeout=True,
        connection_class=RequestsHttpConnection,
        pool_maxsize=pool_maxsize,
    )

def bulk_index_docs(opensearch_client, docs, batch_size=100):
    # Index documents in batches
    for i in range(0, len(docs), batch_size):
        batch = docs[i:i+batch_size]
        bulk_body = []
        for doc in batch:
            doc_id = doc.get("id", f"doc_{i}")
            bulk_body.append({"index": {"_index": INDEX_NAME, "_id": doc_id}})
            bulk_body.append(doc)

        try:
            response = opensearch_client.bulk(body=bulk_body)
            if response.get("errors"):
                logger.error("Some documents failed to index.")
            else:
                # In a minimal reproducible example, we won't log successes to stdout
                pass
        except Exception as e:
            logger.error(f"Bulk indexing failed: {str(e)}")

def main():
    # Minimal example documents
    docs = [
        {"id": "1", "name": "Alice", "updated_at": "2024-12-17T10:00:00Z"},
        {"id": "2", "name": "Bob", "updated_at": "2024-12-17T10:05:00Z"},
    ]

    client = create_opensearch_client(timeout=15, max_retries=3, pool_maxsize=5)
    bulk_index_docs(client, docs, batch_size=1)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()


Connection options can be passed to underlying objects as kwargs. Hard to help further without an [mcve]

updated to intro an mre

"I can tweak in the OpenSearch Python client or requests library?" You are already setting the relevant options so next option could be to profile the failure to know how long the glitch lasts and may be reconfigure the client and retry with smaller batchs/longer timeouts. When conditions return to normal, resume with regular rate. Or perhaps set advanced urllib3 options like backoff_factor. Seems like OpenSearch accepts all those keywords and passes them to pool/connections.

The glitch is pretty consisntent. I'm wondering if it's an aws type thing

The other thought is maybe there are specific things that we can edit.

More detailed information would help you; size/kind of docs to index, number of batch run when the error occurred, etc.

It's a pretty small doc and I'm getting the error on the 2nd run

Did you check the service SLA?

it hsould be able to resolve more than 2 requests

But that means 200 docs or more, right? May be the service has a quota.

Add this option http_compress = True and check best practices
